# Elegant way to return element to display:none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, display

I have a dropdown, and a list of elements that default to `display:none` with css.
Currently, when an element is selected from the dropdown it's changed to `display:block`

What I'm missing, is how to change the element *back* to `display:none` once a new one is selected. I know I could write a loop to constantly check every element and change it to `display:none` but that seems cumbersome. 
My real problem has about 100 elements, and it seems wasteful to re-hide all of them when 99 of them will already be hidden.

Curious what the most elegant way to do this in jQuery (or javascript) is. A fiddle of what I have is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/3w66k51z/4/

Thanks!

Comment: Is your fiddle working?

Comment: good spot @Paul it is now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add state so that you know the currently shown item (if any) and hide just that one element. I understand you don't want to hide *all* items when most of them will already be hidden.

[Here is a simple implementation of this idea.](https://jsfiddle.net/zdobry1r/2/)

(I imagine your real problem involves many more hidden items than the fiddle. If not — maybe even if so — this may be a premature optimization, and there’s nothing wrong with calling `.hide()` or whatever on all items.)

Comment: Alan that is exactly my issue. my real problem has about 60 more hidden items than the fiddle, and it seems wasteful to re-hide every item that's already hidden. And, only one item will be shown at a time.

Comment: @Acoustic77 Great. I’ve made this change on a fork of your fiddle and updated my answer to link to it. https://jsfiddle.net/zdobry1r/2/

Comment: Thanks! I assume this is faster, but now I'm incredibly curious about the relative speed of checking with an if vs hiding all of them. I'm going to go with this answer, will report back if I manage to compare them though!

Answer (score 5):

I've added `$(".sReport").hide();` before your .show() call in order to hide all of the elements.

[jQuery.hide() will set the element's display to none](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3w66k51z/5/)

Comment: That seems pretty darn elegant! I'll give a few moments to see if anyone else has anything especially interesting and then mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Acoustic77 Since you won't feel any difference between hide all elements or just one, IMO this is the cleanest way. If you want more elegance you can use a fade transition (eg. https://jsfiddle.net/c5rcdut5/).

Comment: I agree this is cleaner, but my gut tells me it comes at the cost of some speed. You're right that it may not though. I'd love to see an optimization comparison

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil =)](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Answer (score 0):

Create array of your element then create a function to hide all elements but not the one you want to be display.